# Artefacts with subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm a beginner in blender and I follow a tutorial.

I checked everything I thought but I can't correct artefacts rendering on the neck of my guitar project. They appear with subdivision surface applied.

[image: artifacts]

Someone could help me to understand what is wrong? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can't find out what cause this. But if you turn on the Auto Smooth (located in Objectdata Properties>>Normals) and increase the angle to keep the edges smooth it solves the problem.

Comment: Unmerged vertices on the mirror axis, I think.. Shift-C cursor to origin, cursor as pivot, select the axis loop, SX0. (BTW. you have some flipped normals on some of your nuts and bolts)

Comment: if you put the Merge Limit of the Mirror at 0 it will work, the vertex is probably a little bit into the mirror side

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I change the Mirror merge limit to 0 and it works.